# Ограничение времени создания записи через SQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Имеется POSTGRES таблица для хранения истории голосований юзера за рестораны:

```
CREATE TABLE votes
(
    id                       INTEGER        DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id              INTEGER                                   NOT NULL,
    restaurant_id     INTEGER                                   NOT NULL,
    datetime            TIMESTAMP   DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)          REFERENCES users (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Пункты ТЗ диктуют следующие условия:

1) Пользователь может голосовать за один ресторан один раз в день;

2) Если пользователь пытается **повторно** проголосовать до 11:00 текущего дня - его голос обновляется (меняется id ресторана, за который он проголосовал)

3) Если пользователь пытается осуществить вышеуказанное действие после 11:00 - ему сообщается о запрете на подобное действие(ошибка)

Можно ли реализовать эти пункты на стороне SQL, и если да - то как?

На текущий момент метод в сервисе выглядит так:

```
public Vote vote(Restaurant restaurant, User user) {
        Vote voteFromRepo = voteRepository.findByUserIdAndDate(user.getId(), LocalDate.now());
        if (voteFromRepo == null || (voteFromRepo != null && !isTimeOver())) {
            return voteRepository.save(new Vote(restaurant, user));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Но мне хотелось бы ловить ошибку на стороне SQL и обрабатывать, а не лезть в базу за наличием

Comment: (2) Вставка выполняется запросом INSERT .. ON CONFLICT, где условием конфликта является индексное выражение `date_trunc('day', datetime)`. Соответственно при наличии записи за текущий день выполняется обновление, при отсутствии вставка новой записи. (3) выполняется соответствующим CHECK CONSTRAINT, проверяющим, что время не превышает 11:00, и блокирующим вставку/обновление при нарушении условия.

Comment: ТЗ противоречиво. (2) и (1) не согласованы. Формально цепь голосований ресторан1-ресторан2-ресторан1 допускается (2), но не допускается (1). При этом структура таблицы не позволяет отследить такую цепь и заблокировать повторное голосование за ресторан1.

Comment: Как я понимаю то все просто

В период с 00:00 до 10:59 пользователю можно голосовать сколько угодно, обновляя restaurant_id если запись в базе уже существует. 
В период с 11:00 до 23:59 обновления запрещены, можно только добавить запись в базу в случае её отсутствия.

Comment: @Morewind совершенно верно

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю что нужно идти смотреть про триггеры и хранимые процедуры - [Триггерные процедуры](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/plpgsql-trigger)

Как я вижу - сделать триггер на вставку/обновление записи в базе и в нем проверять условия по ТЗ. Конкретнее не подскажу, к сожалению.

Comment: Нефиг тут делать триггеру, всё прекрасно организуется на уровне контроля целостности данных.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендуемое решение.

В таблицу записываются ВСЕ попытки голосования - каждая создаёт новую запись. При подсчёте результатов записи позднее 11:00 игнорируются, а из тех, что не позднее 11:00 для результата берётся запись с максимальным временем.

При необходимости перед записью голоса производится запрос в БД на предмет наличия ранних действительных голосований, и выдаётся сообщение с диагностикой (и сведениями о том, какой голос будет учтён). Решение о фиксации голоса возлагается на пользователя.

Comment: 1)противоречия между пунктами нет. если взять какие-то сутки, и пользователь не голосовал - он может запросто голосовать в любое время.

но если он сделал это после 11:00 - то свой голос он обновить не сможет

Comment: 2)таблицу можно изменить, это тестовое задание

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin Вы что-то всё мешаете в одну кучу. Распишите для себя все возможные процессы (голосование до 11 и голосование после 11) и все возможные условия (за текущий день голоса нет, голос есть, за текущий ресторан голоса нет, голос есть, ...) - получите с десяток частных вариантов. И распишите действие для каждого частного варианта. Тогда появится хоть какая-то ясность.